# Can I imitate a tie_breaker_field in OpenSearch with search_after pagination?

Tags: opensearch

I do the sorting by datetime and have the recurrent values.

```
#1 "2023-01-03 19:57:38"
#2 "2023-01-03 19:57:38"
...
#3 "2023-01-03 19:57:39"
#4 "2023-01-03 19:57:39"
...
```

This makes leaks of the docs while paginating using `search_after` parameter. According to the dataset above imagine first 10K docs ends with #1 value, so the next 10K will start with #3. #2 is missed thus.

After searching this [Official OpenSearch page](https://opensearch.org/docs/2.4/opensearch/search/paginate/#the-search_after-parameter), [issues on GitHub](https://github.com/opensearch-project/OpenSearch/issues) and other Internet resources by myself I did not find any solution, even custom one. If I use some unique field as a 2d sorting parameter it can help partly, but makes the response data ordering much more mixed (`id` field was tried).
What I expect for clean results is a usage of something like `tie_breaker_field` such as ElasticSearch engine provides. It is tied up with `pit_id` and has a unique value for the current `pit_id` dataset.
If there is no basic way to do this in OpenSearch, is it possible to generate some unique value imitating a `tie_breaker_field` tying it up to the `pit_id`?

Below is a prototype of the request body I use:

```
<CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS> = [
    "size" => <int>,
    "from" => <int>,
    "pit" => [
        "id" => <pit_id>
    ],
    "query" => [...],
    "sort" => [
        'update_at' => 'asc'
    ],
];
```

Comment: Can you elaborate regarding ` data ordering much mixed` ?